# Randomly divide a stream of UUID numbers into 10 buckets

Tags: hash, md5, uuid

I am dealing with a stream of [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). My end goal is to randomly divide those numbers into 10 buckets, i.e. put each one of them into any one of the 10 buckets in such a way that any given moment if I have dealt with `N` UUID numbers from that stream I should have approximately `N/10` numbers in each bucket. I came with up with the following idea:

- Get the 16 byte array equivalent of the given UUID (since each UUID has 128 bits)
- Add up the unsigned value of the 16 bytes to get a positive integer `sum`.
- Get the `sum modulo 100` value.
- The modulo value will belong to either of the 10 buckets depending on its value : Bucket 1 : [0, 9], Bucket 2 : [10, 19], ..... , Bucket 10 : [90, 99].

I tried this experiment for close to about 200,000 UUIDs (and did it with 8 different streams), and observed that each bucket has close to 10% of the total numbers (between range of 9.85% to 10.15%) which seems to be fairly random. My question is:

1. If instead of just taking the sum of the 16 bytes, if I instead take the hash value (let's say `MD5` hash) of the `UUID` and then perform these steps, will I have a better chance of dividing them randomly? A more general question would be, Is there a mathematical way to visualize that hashing can help in these scenarios?
2. If you agree agree with point (1), then what should be a good hashing algorithm to do the same.
3. If you don't agree with point (1), then can you suggest me a better algorithm of doing the same.

Comment: Hashing entire UUID should do the trick. Remember that hash function output is an integer (but many libraries convert it to string in hex/other format).
MD5 should be fine, but you should check the distribution fairness for yourself.

Comment: Did you get a good solution for this question ? Can you share?

Answer (score 2):

In fact the algorithm you described technically does implement a hash function, as it maps the space of UUID to a set of fixed-size, that is, the set of numbers from 1 to 10.

Your question 1. then becomes the question of how uniformly distributed is the output  of the hash function defined by your algorithm.

Whether your hash function distributes the output better than, say, MD5, is hard to say a priori, as that will depend on the distribution of the input stream. However, hash functions that come in stock with language libraries (such as MD5) usually implement heuristics to avoid collisions for obviously unfortunate distributions. A concrete example: say your input stream contains only UUIDs from the set

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000010
.
.
.
10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Then all of them will be mapped to bucket 1, whereas MD5 is likely to scramble things around.

You can use a [chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) to measure how well a hash function does on a sample of your input.